# Converter IQueryable para um tipo

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Fiz esse código

```
OrderItem itens = new OrderItem();
            var items = _orderService.GetItemsFromOrder(orderId);
            itens = items.Where(x => x.CurrencyCode == 23).Select(s => new OrderItem { ProductId = s.ProductId, CurrencyCode = s.CurrencyCode.GetValueOrDefault() }).ToList();
```

e está dando esse erro:

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List
>   'CSP.SubscriptionCenter.Core.Domain.Orders.OrderItem' to
>   'CSP.SubscriptionCenter.Core.Domain.Orders.OrderItem'

Mas a lambda eu tipei ela como `OrderItem`, então ficou assim:

> items >> IQueryable
>
> itens >> OrderItem

No caso de CurrencyCode em OrderItem é um nullable, por isso eu fiz isso na expressão

```
CurrencyCode = s.CurrencyCode.GetValueOrDefault()
```

Como resolvo esse erro citado acima?

**OBS:** Na mensagem de erro eu removi os símbolos <>, pois estava dando problemas na hora de quotar e coloquei aspa(').

Comment: Está a tentar atribuir uma Lista a uma variável do tipo OrderItem, é esse o erro, qual é a sua questão? Se quer apenas um OrderItem não pode fazer ToList no final.

Answer (score 2):

Como disse o Mauro no comentário, tem um erro de declaração do `itens`. Observe que o retorno no *ToList* é uma lista de `OrderItem` e não um elemento.

Você pode corrigir de duas formas:

```
List<OrderItem> itens = new List<OrderItem>();
var items = _orderService.GetItemsFromOrder(orderId);
itens = items.Where(x => x.CurrencyCode == 23).Select(s => new OrderItem { ProductId = s.ProductId, CurrencyCode = s.CurrencyCode.GetValueOrDefault() }).ToList();
```

Ou retornar somente um elemento por `FirstOrDefault`:

```
OrderItem itens = new OrderItem();
var items = _orderService.GetItemsFromOrder(orderId);
itens = items.Where(x => x.CurrencyCode == 23).Select(s => new OrderItem { ProductId = s.ProductId, CurrencyCode = s.CurrencyCode.GetValueOrDefault() }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Eu ainda recomendaria a não declarar o tipo e utilizar um `var` para o retorno que você quiser:

```
var itens = items.Where(x => x.CurrencyCode == 23).Select(s => new OrderItem { ProductId = s.ProductId, CurrencyCode = s.CurrencyCode.GetValueOrDefault() }).ToList();
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Thiago, fiz conforme sua sugestão declarando o var itens, última sugestão sua e pego esse erro: `The entity or complex type 'CSP.SubscriptionCenter.Data.OrderItem' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.`

Comment: Eu resolvi isso retornando tudo, sem o select. Aí na controller eu faço o foreach e seleciono o que eu quero realmente. Deixei apenas o where, dessa forma: `var itens = items.Where(x => x.CurrencyCode == 23).ToList();`

Comment: Faça um teste básico: Adicione um ToList antes do Select. 
Deve resolver, mas considere a forma que isso está sendo feita no banco de dados. Isso ocorre porque o Entity está tentando rodar a conversão no comando SQL para o banco, colocando o ToList primeiro, você faz a consulta e depois em memória seleciona convertendo para o objeto tipado.